# How to use the window location

Tags: javascript, html, dom

So i wanna create a form with a textbox and a button that on click opens the url that i type inside the textbox,any advice on how to use a function to make it work?

```js
function open(url) {
  var win = window.location(url, '_blank');
  win.focus();
}
```

```html
<form>
  Give Url:<br>
  <input type="url" name="url" placeholder="http://www.example.com"><br>
</form>
<button type="button" onclick="open(url)">Open Url</button>
```

Comment: Your code has an error: *Uncaught ReferenceError: url is not defined*

Comment: yeah i find the same and still it doesnt run correctly

Answer (score 0):

Use `window.open`:

```
function open(url) {
    var win = window.open(url, "_blank");
    win.focus();
}
```

Comment: Ironically, if OP hadn't have over-written "open", wouldn't it have defaulted to `window.open` ?

Comment: I agree @DerekPollard.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're passing in an unknown variable, called *url*:

```js
function open(url) {
  var win = window.location(url, '_blank');
  win.focus();
}
```

```html
<form>
  Give Url:<br>
  <input id="url" type="url" name="url" placeholder="http://www.example.com"><br>
</form>
<button type="button" onclick="open(document.getElementById('url').value)">Open Url</button>
```

In my snippet, I am passing the value of the input element with the ID of `url`

Answer (score 0):

You're not submitting any form data anywhere, so you don't need a `form` element and your `input` doesn't need a `name` attribute.

Just call `window.open(url)` and [you should not be setting up your event handlers in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43459890/javascript-function-doesnt-work-when-link-is-clicked/43459991#43459991) (even though you see everyone else do it).

The code below works, but not here in the Stack Overflow code snippet environment. [But, you can test the same code here.](https://jsfiddle.net/1muh9scw/)

```js
let tb = document.querySelector("input"); // Get a reference to the textbox

// Get a reference to the button and set up the click event handler for it
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", function () {
  var win = window.open(tb.value);
});
```

```html
Give Url:<br>
<input type="url" placeholder="http://www.example.com"><br>
<button type="button">Open Url</button>
```

Comment: It is always ironic to me that for so long we were told to separate Javascript and HTML, then react and vue come along and blow that all to shreds

Comment: @DerekPollard That's not true at all. You are comparing apples and oranges. When we talk about not putting inline event attributes into HTML, we're talking about the final code that will be executed. When you talk about the practice in frameworks, that's not the code that actually gets executed. That code is converted into other code by the framework first. This is well-documented.

Comment: Not at all apples to oranges, both are maintained by developers - which is where the fallacy that this was bad came from, the final product matters very little. My point being, the concepts don't hold water when it comes to implementation because, as we can see with react and vue, it makes development easier and quicker.

Comment: @DerekPollard And the debate rages on. One is code that will be executed and one is code that will turned into something else. One is an environment where you have a choice on how to do it and one is an environment where you don't. And with HTML, you can get different results depending on which way you go - - it's not a purely stylistic choice.